# neo4j cypher toInt function

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In the neo4j Cypher refcard (http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/) under Functions sections there is this definition:

```
toInt({expr})

Converts the given input in an integer if possible; otherwise it returns NULL.
```

If I try it in Cypher console I get this:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n:Document) return toInt(n.date);
==> SyntaxException: Unknown function 'toInt' (line 1, column 27)
==> "match (n:Document) return toInt(n.date)"
==>                            ^
neo4j-sh (?)$
```

(In my case n.date is a string representation of that date.)

Also in the neo4j documentation there is not mention of this function: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-function.html.

Can anyone solve this puzzle?

Comment: can you post the query?

Comment: Should be in 2.1.0-M01, I think there was some version mixup with the refcard.

Answer (score 1):

toInt and toFloat are not yet added in 2.0.1 release. Check at this [link](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/master/packaging/standalone/standalone-enterprise/src/main/distribution/text/enterprise/CHANGES.txt).{line 28} Its been planned to release with 2.0.2